# windows 11 mouse pointer style resets after reboot

Tags: windows, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 home edition, and I like to have the mouse pointer style be the one that is dark on light backgrounds and vice versa. However, when I change it to that style, then reboot, the mouse pointer just reverts back to the default of "always light mouse pointer style".

Pretty sure this is a bug in windows.

Comment: Are you synchronizing your Settings to multiple devices by chance?

Comment: no I'm not. I've only been using a single desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah never mind, it was not because of the reboot, but rather because of changing the theme. I change the theme from dark to light very often, and every time, the mouse pointer goes back to the default.